# How can I convert watermarked, citation-filled Hebrew PDFs to audio?

Tags: pdf, audio, pypdf

I need to read quite a few papers for a degree I'm doing, and I want to listen to them instead of reading them. These papers are in PDF form, often watermarked, full of citations and sometimes in Hebrew. This means that any of the commercial pdf to audio tools that I've tried so far failed pretty hard.
I would like to find/ create some PDF to audio pipeline in which I could tweak some things from pdf to pdf (i.e. write some regular expressions to recognize and remove parts I don't want read out loud), while still having most of the process automated.

So far I've tried using pypdf2 in python to convert my pdfs to text. The results are very inconsistent - letters jumping around, spaces where they shouldn't be, or no spaces at all. That being said their visitor is super useful to remove watermarks and citations.
I've also tried pdfplumber, but the Hebrew wasn't even recognized as rtl.
I can't really add the documents here, they are not for distribution (and have my name and personal details embedded into them).
The solution doesn't have to be in python, or in any programming language for that matter. Any alternative approaches, good resources or even general ideas are very welcome.

Comment: pdftotext is perfect! seriously, wow! and balcon is also super useful. thank you so much! edit: how can I mark this post answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Words as audio would be in effect plain text as waves.

So you are right to convert `pdftotext -layout -enc UTF-8`
other options are available such as

- `-enc ISO-8859-8` for Hebrew
- `-nopgbrk` for  mutiple blocks of pages using
- `-f ## -l ##` for page range
  and a switch to disregard diagonal text (watermarks)
- `-nodiag`              : discard diagonal text
  currently windows version is 23-05 https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows/releases

Then convert using TTS into mp3 or whatever.

There is also a nice tool that does Text Extract and TTS as parts of Balabolka
http://cross-plus-a.com/balabolka.htm

So in my PDF Viewer I can send one or more pages to be read aloud by Hazel

```
"C:\Apps\Utils\TTS\Balcon\Balcon.exe" -tray -n "Hazel" -v 100 -w "c:\data\printouts\reader.wav" -f "%1"
```

Again it is currently 2023-05 updates and possibly more output options than Poppler

Hebrew to MP3 is not commonly found in free TTS readers (the voice phonetics/inflections are fairly unique to that language). One online  dedicated Hebrew audio reader is https://app.almareader.com/ which has mp3 download.

Comment: I ran into a somewhat unexpected problem - I can't seem to find Hebrew voices. Even in the commercial space I only found 3 (very bad) voices. Do you know where I could find a Hebrew voice for free? even if its not a very good one XD
Also - windows has some TTS in its normal language packs, I couldn't find a way to let Balcon use it though. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I managed to make the hebrew readable in console, if thats the use of poppler, then I'm ok :) if thats not what you meant, then sorry, I'm not really understanding ><
narakeet is actually pretty high quality! doesn't read numbers, which is just weird, but beyond that the sounds is great. only issue is, its *very* expensive. one academic paper will cost me about 50 dollars, and I don't have that kind of money. 
anyhow, thank you for the effort, and if you encounter something in the wild please share!

Comment: ended up resolving the issue by using google cloud api. relatively cheap and unless you use it quite a lot, even free :)